# Delete tabs at the end of each row in logfile

Tags: excel, matlab

my logfiles are full of tabs at the end of each row. The Problem is, that I need the tabs before, for the logfile to be readable. I can replace 2 tabs with nothing, to not delete the ones I need. But then I still have 1 tab at the end of each row and since I have a lot of logfiles and they are very long it would take me forever to delete those manually.

Can someone give me a function or skript to delete tabs after the last character of each row (the rows do not end at the same column).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, but would it work to import into excel as tab separated (treat multiple separators as one) and then export again?

Answer (score 1):

try `regexprep`

```
>> noTabs = regexprep( origText, '\t$', '' );
```